# References in overleaf latex

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I am using overleaf to run latex file with bibliography.bib file attached for references in footnote format.

But the references come after compiling the tex file too many times.

Can you kindly help me if there is some process to overcome this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is simply the way TeX works, and there's no way around it. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: But in overleaf I can only see the option Recompile. Is there some option like texmaker, generally I compile bibtex, then pdflatex and then compile the file to get the references.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You might want to ask Overleaf support. You could probably add a custom `latexmkrc` file see [here](https://ja.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_use_latexmkrc_with_Overleaf:_examples_and_techniques) but that isn't likely to be very practical. If you don't add new references, recompiling should only compile twice anyway.